# Speed up mouse wheel scrolling in Chrome on Mint/Cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint, chrome, cinnamon

On Mint Cinnamon scrolling in Chrome with the mouse wheel is very slow. How can I speed it up?

Things I have tried:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/118283/change-mouse-wheel-scroll-speed-in-chrome-on-12-04-edit-starter-bar-commandline

https://askubuntu.com/questions/254367/permanently-fix-chrome-scroll-speed

Command line deprecated, and the Smooth Scrolling extension is juddery and unreliable. Sometimes it doesn't kick in, then starts working again a few seconds later.

**xinput**

Only managed to reduce scroll speed, couldn't make it faster.

**imwheel**

No effect.

Answer (score 3):

A solution is available in [Setup the mouse scroll wheel speed](https://mintguide.org/other/643-setup-the-mouse-scroll-wheel-speed.html).

1. `sudo apt install imwheel`
2. `cd ~/; wget http://www.nicknorton.net/mousewheel.sh -O imwheel-script.sh; chmod +x imwheel-script.sh; sh imwheel-script.sh; exit`
3. Startup. To have utility imwheel working at every system startup add imwheel to startup list.

Comment: You will note that I already tried imwheel and it didn't work.